# Temp table not running

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, temp-tables

Whenever I run this temp table in google bigquery sql i get "use of create temporary table requires a script"?

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE products AS
  SELECT product, product_color,
  FROM `radiant-oven-328313.customer_data.customer_purchase` 
  WHERE product = "fan";
```

Does this mean I need to insert data into my table or is my syntax correct??
To insert into my table, I've tried the additional line of code below:

```
Select product_color as White_color
FROM products 
WHERE product_color = "white"
FROM `radiant-oven-328313.customer_data.customer_purchase`
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Please dont' SHOUT when posting here. Text in ALL CAPS is more difficult to read and understand, and SHOUTING won't get you help any faster. It's also rather impolite to SHOUT at us when you're asking us for free help.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to specify the name and types for the columns.
For example:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE product (product STRING, product_color STRING)
AS
  SELECT product, product_color
  FROM `radiant-oven-328313.customer_data.customer_purchase`
  WHERE product="fan"
;
```

This will let you create a temporary table and interact with it within your session.  However if you are not using this as part of a script already and just need it as part of your SQL Query logic you may want to consider using a CTE or sub-query instead.

For more information on temp tables:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting-concepts#temporary_tables

For more information on CTEs:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#with_clause